# Blind Position Online Prediction

Tags: python, online-machine-learning, creme

new here.
I'm currently working on my MSc thesis that consists of developing a set of blinds/shutters that predict the user's behavior and set the position automatically, according to the user's habits and likes.
I'm using Online Learning to solve my problem, specifically the library creme (python). The problem is I can't get good enough results, with an MAE of around 24, which is way too much. Do you guys have any experience/ideas on how to solve a problem like this?
I'm getting these numbers with a model like this:

```
model = compose.Discard('Year', 'Timestamp')
model += feature_extraction.Agg(on='Radiation', by='Month', how=stats.Mean())
model |= linear_model.PARegressor()
model = time_series.Detrender(regressor=model, window_size=105120) #Around a year
```

And with the following features:

- Timestamp
- Year
- Quarter
- Month
- Weekofyear
- Dayofyear
- Dayofmonth
- Dayofweek
- Hour
- Minute
- Holiday
- Temperature
- Humidity
- Radiation

Being Position the label

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of creme. Your task looks very interesting!

I recommend that you open a [dedicated issue](https://github.com/creme-ml/creme/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=performance_issue.md&title=) on GitHub. In particular, we will need access to a dataset in order to reproduce the performance you're describing.